# Number of interaction of early universe

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, cosmology, dark-matter, kinetic-theory

I am reading *An introduction to particle dark matter* by Stefano Profumo. I am struggling on a derivation.

As given from the text, in the early universe $\frac{\dot{T}}{T}=-\frac{\dot{a}}{a}=-H$, assume rate $\Gamma \sim T^n$, then total number of interaction is given by $N_{int} = \int_{t}^{\infty} \Gamma(t') dt' = \frac{1}{n-2} (\frac{\Gamma}{H})_t$.

I am not able to reduplicate the integral result.

Comment: Do you have any reference? Article, equation numbers?

Comment: Hi, the reference is An introduction to particle dark matter by Stefano Profumo page 248- 249.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point in Stefano's derivation is that you need to assume radiation domination. In this situation, you have $a(t)\propto t^{1/2}$, therefore $\dot{T}/T=-H=-1/2t$, and you find that $T=t^{-1/2}$ and the Hubble rate is $H=1/2t$. Now, the integral becomes
$$ \begin{align}
  N_{int}=\int_{t}^{\infty} T^{\prime \, n} \, dt^{\prime} = \int_{t}^{\infty} t^{\prime \, -\frac{n}{2}} \, dt^{\prime} = \frac{2}{2-n}\left[t^{\prime \, \frac{2-n}{2}}\right]_{t}^{\infty}
\end{align}$$
But with time, the temperature drops, and so does the number of interactions. You can then safely discard the limit at infinity, and you are left with
$$ \begin{align}
  N_{int}= \frac{2}{n-2}t^{\frac{2-n}{2}} = \frac{2}{n-2}T^{n-2} = \frac{1}{n-2}T^{n} T^{-2} = \frac{1}{n-2} \left(\frac{\Gamma}{H}\right)_{t}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't aware the radiation assumption.